# Can't get data from XML with xpath if the element has attributes

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to parse a [GetCapabilities](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getcapabilities) XML with pure JavaScript. The problem is, when the parent element has attributes, it returns an empty string. However if I remove all attributes from XML, the parser will give a correct result. See the example bellow. Any idea why this is happening?

```js
// Example 1: with attributes

let xmlString = `<WMS_Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.3.0" updateSequence="1523788994171" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd">
                     <Service>
                         <Name>WMS</Name>
                     </Service>
                </WMS_Capabilities>`;
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');
let result = doc.evaluate('/WMS_Capabilities/Service/Name', doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);


document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = result.stringValue;

// Example 2: without attributes

let xmlStringWithoutAttr = `<WMS_Capabilities>
                                <Service>
                                    <Name>WMS</Name>
                                </Service>
                            </WMS_Capabilities>`;
let doc2 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStringWithoutAttr,'text/xml');
let result2 = doc.evaluate('/WMS_Capabilities/Service/Name', doc2, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);

document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = result2.stringValue;
```

```html
<p>With attributes: <span id="result1"></span></p>
<p>Without attributes: <span id="result2"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute `xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms"` is a default namespace declaration and puts those elements into that namespace so with XPath 1.0 to select them you need to use a prefix bound to the namespace to be able to select them. With that API you have you need

```js
// Example 1: with attributes

let xmlString = `<WMS_Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.3.0" updateSequence="1523788994171" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd">
                     <Service>
                         <Name>WMS</Name>
                     </Service>
                </WMS_Capabilities>`;
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');
let result = doc.evaluate('/wms:WMS_Capabilities/wms:Service/wms:Name', doc, function(prefix) { if (prefix === 'wms') return 'http://www.opengis.net/wms'; else return null; }, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);


document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = result.stringValue;

// Example 2: without attributes

let xmlStringWithoutAttr = `<WMS_Capabilities>
                                <Service>
                                    <Name>WMS</Name>
                                </Service>
                            </WMS_Capabilities>`;
let doc2 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStringWithoutAttr,'text/xml');
let result2 = doc2.evaluate('/WMS_Capabilities/Service/Name', doc2, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);

document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = result2.stringValue;
```

```html
<p>With attributes: <span id="result1"></span></p>
<p>Without attributes: <span id="result2"></span></p>
```

You can use any prefix you like, you just need to make sure the function you use as the third argument to `evaluate` returns the namespace URI you want to bind to that prefix, that is, the namespace URI of the elements you need to select.